# 32 bit JDK on 64 bit Weblogic Server

Tags: weblogic, 32bit-64bit, java, weblogic-10.x

Is it possible to run an application on a 64 bit Weblogic 10.3.2 Server instance with a 32 bit JDK?
The reason for me to doing this is getting an exceptions while running my program using 64 bit JDK.

```
UCFWin32JNI.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

The error is gone when using 32 bit JDK.
If it is possible, then how?

Thanks!

Comment: 32-bit applications can use 32-bit libraries, 64-bit applications can only use 64-bit libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 32-bit version of a library cannot be loaded and used by a 64-bit JVM, and vice versa.

Moreover, `UCFWin32JNI.dll` does not appear to be a WebLogic library at all. In fact, it appears to be a library from Documentum. You ought to be looking for a 64-bit version of that library (if it is available) as it appears to be a 32-bit version going by the name and the error message produced. Finally, you'll need to place the 64-bit version in one of the directories constituting `java.library.path`.

Answer (score 0):

No problems at all running a 32bit JVM on a 64bit platform. In fact, for some applications it can actually be more efficient, due to the fact that certain data types are innately larger on a 64bit JVM (ints I think are an example of this from memory)

A 64bit JVM provides all sorts of advantages for an application requiring access to a larger heap, but there's no harm at all in running a 32bit JVM.